# Encrypting PDF Documents

Tags: flutter

In my flutter application I download pdf documents from the server. I do not want the documents to be shareable. I currently store these documents in the application directory of my app so they are not visible in file or directory manager.

The problem is users with rooted android devices. I wanted to encrypt the PDF files after downloading have googled but can't seem to find any info on how to do this.  All I see is how to encrypt plain text files.

Please note that I have no control of the PDF files being uploaded to the server so I cannot encrypt them at the time of upload.

I would like information on how to encrypt downloaded PDF files or if there is an alternate solution to my problem.

Comment: Are you looking for Android only solution? I can help you out with Android.

Comment: So my app is in flutter.  I was hoping for a flutter(dart) solution not native java or kotlin.

Comment: It is a dart plugin I wrote that I use in my Flutter app to password protect and save PDF files in documents folder. But you are right it uses native Java and method calls.

Comment: Hi, that sounds interesting, does it password protect existing pdf files?

Comment: Yes, it does but works on Android only

Comment: I would like this solution please. :)

Comment: How did you store the documents in the application directory of my app, can you please share?